# SSH ask for password on a device with no password

Tags: windows-10, ssh, passwords, ssh-keys

I am trying to access my desktop via my laptop and to do so I setup an ssh server on my desktop. I allowed the firewall and everything. now whenever I try to connect via ssh to the desktop it keeps asking me for a password which I don't have as my desktop isn't set up with a password. I tried to do it with the keys instead but even that asks for a password whenever I try to copy it. Is there maybe a default password that is used?

Comment: You need to set a password on your desktop.

Comment: so there is no way of doing it without a password?

Comment: You can copy the public key some other way (USB/cloud/…).

Comment: Your account most certainly has a password.  It's either an empty password or it contains characters.  **It's not possible to have a Windows account without a password.** You can configure OpenSSH to accept key authentication.  The process is well documented.

Comment: yes it is an empty password but whenever I just hit enter and leave it blank it tells me its incorrect. And when I tried with key authentication by copying the keys via usb, it still asks me for password even after I made an authorized_users file and sets the permissions.

Comment: "even after I made an authorized_users file and sets the permissions" – For all SSH servers I know `authorized_users` is as relevant as `authorized_raccoons`, i.e. totally irrelevant, unless the config states otherwise. The default relevant file is `authorized_keys` in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the very same issue, and I set a password on the passwordless account, and it works.